# React ES5: Pass a function to another function resulted in "not a function" error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to passed a function from one component(CompB) to another function that is in the another component(CompA) so it will be executed when `setState` is completed.

However, I ran into `Uncaught TypeError: CallBack is not a function` error.

The code snippet is following:

```
var CompA = React.createClass({

  foo: function(form, CallBack){
    var that = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: '/someurl',
      type: 'someAction',
      data: $(form).serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        that.setState({"id": data.id}, function(){
          CallBack();
        });
      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log("Error")
      }
    });
  },

  InnerCallBack: function(SuccessCallBack){
    this.foo($("#some_form"), SuccessCallBack); 
  },


  render:function(){
    return(
      <CompB passedCallBack = {this.InnerCallBack} />
      <button onClick={this.submit}>Submit</button>
    )
  }
})

var CompB = React.createClass({
  addWords: function(){
    var bar = this.state.words;

    bar.push({
       "someData": "",
       "words": "dafadf"
    });

    this.setState({
      "words" : bar
    })
  },

  callbackWrapper: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.props.passedCallBack(this.addWords());
  },

  render: function(){
    return(
      <button onClick={this.callbackWrapper}>
    )
  }
})
```

**My guess and attempts**:
1:The research I have done on SO suggested a binding problem. However, that post was about ES6. my version is ES5,which has the auto-binding as far as i know?

2: Right now I am suspecting it has to do with scoping? I am suspecting this line `<CompB passedCallBack = {this.InnerCallBack} />` because no parameter is passed? but I thought in react passing a function as props does not require a parameter?

**What I tried to achieve**
1: I am trying to find out what caused this error and a way to fix it.

2: Another problem I have with this code snippet is that when the button from CompB is clicked, the onClick function from CompA is fired as well. I understood that it has something to do with DOM's event bubbling and tried to use `evemt.preventDefault()` to fix it, but it did not fix it.(This can be a seperate SO post,so I am not worrying about it at this point)

Comment: Tracing how `foo` is called shows that it is called via `this.props.passedCallBack(this.addWords());`, where the argument passed to `this.props.passedCallBack` (`InnerCallBack`) is supposed to be a callback function. `this.addWords` however **does not a return a function**. It returns `undefined`. If you mean to pass `this.addWords` as callback then don't call it: `this.props.passedCallBack(this.addWords);`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: `React.createClass` automatically calls `.bind(instance)` on all methods.

Comment: @FelixKling: That's weird, because I tried it before voting to close, and `this` did not have the right value. But I trust you, I must have mis-observed somehow. I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i thought React. createClass calls .bind ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: `¯\_(ツ)_/¯` If it didn't get the right `this` value then the OP would never get this error since `foo` would never be called.

Comment: @FelixKling yes, `foo` is called via the `innercallback` function.And yes I meant to pasas `this.addWords` as a callback of `foo`. How should I call it then? And why does this.addWords return `undefined`?

Comment: *"How should I call it then?"* You don't. `this.addWords` is called inside the `foo` via `CallBack()`. You just have to pass the function itself to `passedCallBack`. *"And why does this.addWords return undefined?"* Because any function that doesn't explicitly `return` something returns `undefined`: `function foo() {}; console.log('Return value', foo());`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Pass a function to another function resulted in “not a function” error

You are not passing a function.

- `foo` is called as `this.foo($("#some_form"), SuccessCallBack);` in `InnerCallBack`.
- `InnerCallBack` is called as `this.props.passedCallBack(this.addWords());`

I.e. you are **calling** `addWords` and pass its **return value** to `passedCallBack`. `passedCallBack` expects to be passed a function, but `addWords` does not return anything (hence it returns `undefined`). Therefore `SuccessCallBack` will be `undefined`.

If you intend to pass `addWords` as callback then don't call it:

```
this.props.passedCallBack(this.addWords);
//                                    ^^ no calling parenthesis here
```

Comment: the error message remains. Is it because the function call has no parameter here? `<CompB passedCallBack = {this.InnerCallBack} />`

Comment: No. What do you get for `console.log(this.addWords)` inside `callbackWrapper` ?

Comment: function () {
     var bar = this.state.words;

    bar.push({
       "someData": "",
       "words": "dafadf"
    });

Comment: so it actually is a function.

Comment: And what does `console.log(SuccessCallBack)` inside `InnerCallBack` give you?

Comment: same thing,  
function () { var bar = this.state.words; bar.push({ "someData": "", "words": "dafadf" });. So it does gets passed.

Comment: So you cannot get the same error. `CallBack` inside `foo` will be a function.

Comment: but when i do console.log(CallBack) inside the `foo`, it returns `undefined`

Comment: That's not possible. You are passing `SuccessCallBack` as second argument to `foo`.

Comment: I know what you mean, but it did happen, and I will look into that for couple minutes.

Comment: You were right tho, i have been passing the function wrong the whole time.